# Inserting into a DB only once using DB Facade

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to populate a user table with a row that is generated once a user logs into the system in a specific time frame. However, given the fact that a user can logout and log in again, i dont want to populate the table with another row for the same user. I also want to be able to generate another row if let's say the user logs again tomorrow (most likely, there will be other users logged after him in the table). Here's what i've managed to achieve so far:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
$Shifts = DB::table('shifts')->latest()->first();

if ($datetime->format('H:i') >= '05:50' && $datetime->format('H:i') <= '17:10') {
    DB::table('attendanceTable')->insert(['user_id' => $request->loggedUserId, 'shift_id' => $Shifts->id, 'created_at' => $datetime, 'updated_at' => $datetime]);
}
```

Here's the table structure:

```
 Schema::create('attendanceTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('shift_id');
        $table->timestamps();
```

I've tried using `insertOrIgnore` method, but i'm getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insertOrIgnore()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 'day' field on the `attendanceTable` and make the combination of the `user_id` and `day` unique

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('shift_id');
$table->date('day');
$table->unique(['user_id', 'day']);
$table->timestamps();
```

Now you have a unique constraints that doesn't allow an attendance to be inserted for the same user in the same day

## Note: You're not using Eloquent, you're using the DB Facade

Learn how to insert with Eloquent ORM [here](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Now to insert a record you can have a condition like this

```php
$already_exists = DB::table('attendanceTable')->where('user_id', $request->loggedUserId)
                    ->where('shift_id', $Shifts->id)
                    ->where('day', today())
                    ->exists();
if ($datetime->format('H:i') >= '05:50' && $datetime->format('H:i') <= '17:10' && !$already_exists) {
```

Comment: Hmm, that's a great idea! And while inserting in the table, i'll use the DateTime object to populate said day, thanks!